# How to manage files in ipod with kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ipod

I'm trying KDE plasma.

I've found I can't manage files (not just music and photos) in my ipod like a U-disk with Kubuntu 14.04.

But when I use Ubuntu and Nautilus, my ipod performs like a simple U-disk.

which lib should I install to manage my files in ipod?

Answer (score 1):

maybe ifuse+kio_afc is the solution.

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse
```

and then, download and compile [kio_afc](https://github.com/JonathanBeck/kio_afc)

However, aio_afc's last update was in 2010...

Answer (score 0):

There is a application named as gtkpod, install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```

and open it.

Source: [ubuntu-apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gtkpod/)

Comment: I have seen that before, but can it work as an plug-in with nautilus or dolphin? NOT a single application.